# How do i configure neovim to remember open tabs when opening a directory?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Basically, I'd like to emulate the same behaviour as VSCode. When I open a directory in VSCode, it automatically, opens all the previously open tabs. This way, every time i open up an old project, I don't have to reopen all those files again.

How do i do this in neovim? The behaviour I'm expecting is:

1. I have the project1 folder open in nvim with `nvim project1/` , project 1 has 3 files open. **file1, file2, file3**
2. I exit out with `:wqall`
3. I go to some other folder to work on something else, `nvim project2/`
4. When i come back to project1 with nvim project1, I want file1,file2,file3 opened up for me, preferably with cursor positions remembered as well.
5. Additonally, if i just type `nvim` in the terminal, I'd like it to just open the last opened project.

I'm pretty new to vim so if there is an existing paradigm or a plugin that helps me jump between projects like this, that would be pretty helpful to find out about

Comment: See `:help session`

Comment: looks like exactly what I need. thanks @mattb